# How to print minimum result in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

MongoDB noob here...

So, I'm trying to print out the minimum value score inside a collection that looks like this...

```
        > db.students.find({'_id': 1}).pretty()
        {
                "_id" : 1,
                "name" : "Aurelia Menendez",
                "scores" : [
                        {
                                "type" : "exam",
                                "score" : 60.06045071030959
                        },
                        {
                                "type" : "quiz",
                                "score" : 52.79790691903873
                        },
                        {
                                "type" : "homework",
                                "score" : 71.76133439165544
                        },
                        {
                                "type" : "homework",
                                "score" : 34.85718117893772
                        }
                ]
        }
```

The incantation I'm using is as such...

```
db.students.aggregate(
    // Initial document match (uses index, if a suitable one is available)
    { $match: {
        _id : 1
    }},

    // Expand the scores array into a stream of documents
    { $unwind: '$scores' },

    // Filter to 'homework' scores 
    { $match: {
        'scores.type': 'homework'
    }},

    // grab the minimum value score
    { $match: {
        'scores.min.score': 1
    }}
)
```

the output i'm getting is this...

```
{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you want to use `$min` here: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_min

Comment: I am...    { $match: {
        'scores.min.score': 1
    }}

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but in the last step of the aggregation what you want to do is group all the scores by student and find the $min value.

Change the last pipeline operation to:

```
{ $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        minScore: {$min: "$scores.score"}
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.students.aggregate(     
{ $unwind:  "$scores" },`
{ $match:{"scores.type":"homework"} }, 
{ $group: { 
    _id : "$_id", 
   maxScore : { $max : "$scores.score"}, 
   minScore: { $min:"$scores.score"} 
  }
});
```

[how to aggregate on each item in collection in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465062/how-to-aggregate-on-each-item-in-collection-in-mongodb/13465287#comment18425674_13465287)