# how to aggregate on each item in collection in mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

MongoDB noob here...

when I do db.students.find().pretty() in the shell I get a long list from my collection...like so..

```
{
    "_id" : 19,
    "name" : "Gisela Levin",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 44.51211101958831
        },
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 0.6578497966368002
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 93.36341655949683
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 49.43132782777443
        }
    ]
}
```

now I've got about over 100 of these...I need to run the following on each of them...

```
lowest_hw_score = 

db.students.aggregate(
    // Initial document match (uses index, if a suitable one is available)
    { $match: {
        _id : 0
    }},

    // Expand the scores array into a stream of documents
    { $unwind: '$scores' },

    // Filter to 'homework' scores 
    { $match: {
        'scores.type': 'homework'
    }},

    // Sort in descending order
    { $sort: {
        'scores.score': 1
    }},

    { $limit: 1}
)
```

So I can run something like this on each result

```
for item in lowest_hw_score:
    print lowest_hw_score
```

Right now "lowest_score" works on only one item I to run this on all items in the collection...how do I do this?

Comment: are you after the lowest score by student? (for homework)

Comment: you just asked the same question here, no?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464232/how-to-print-minimum-result-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.students.aggregate(  
{ $match :  { 'scores.type': 'homework' } },
{ $unwind:  "$scores" },
{ $match:{"scores.type":"homework"} }, 
{ $group: { 
    _id : "$_id", 
   maxScore : { $max : "$scores.score"}, 
   minScore: { $min:"$scores.score"} 
  }
});
```

You don't really need the first $match, but if "scores.type" is indexed, it means it would be used before unwinding the scores. (I don't believe after the $unwind mongo would be able to use the index.)

Result:

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : 19,
        "maxScore" : 93.36341655949683,
        "minScore" : 49.43132782777443
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Edit: tested and updated in mongo shell

Comment: can't see what you're getting, let me know if you still have problems - i'll test it for you shortly